# Can we break double bonds by using laser and heat?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, bond

If it is possible then give an example for it. That chemical reaction is in this process.
step 1: {Reactant + heat(sunlight)} gives weakened bonded product1
step 2: {product1 + laser} gives {one solid product + one gas product}

Comment: You should search for solid state photochemistry, there are many examples.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific